# Smallest $n$ such that $S_4\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, respectively $A_5\times A_5$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a solution for the first question, but the second solution is quite lacking. The solutions are tied together, so I will include both.

For $G=S_4\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, let $(\sigma, i)\in G)$ where $\sigma$ is a four-cycle. The order of $(\sigma, i)$ is 20, therefore $S_n$ must contain an element of order 20.

The smallest such group is $S_9$ with the element $(1234)(56789)$.

The map $\Psi : G \to S_9$ given by $\Psi(\sigma, i) = \sigma \cdot (56789)^i$ is clearly an injective homomorphism. Thus $G$ embeds into $S_9$, and $S_9$ is minimal.

$A_5$ does not contain 4-cycles but contains 5-cycles and 3-cycles. Therefore, the maximum order of an element of $G$ is $5\cdot 3 = 15$.

The smallest $S_n$ with an element of order 15 is $S_8$ with $(12345)(678)$.

Here is where the issue is. I have no idea what the injective homomorphism I have to construct to embed $G$ into $S_8$ is, and I don't know what properties of $S_8$ I have to use to see this connection. I'm not even sure if $S_8$ is the correct group.

Anything would help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is $|G|\nmid |S_8|$. The smallest group that $|G|$ divides is $S_{10}$, which then supports a natural embedding of the first $A_5$ acting on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the second $A_5$ acting on $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$